# Spring Boot Micrometer : timing abstract controller with dynamic metric name

Tags: java, spring, micrometer

We have an abstract generic controller for commons methods :

```java
public abstract class GenericController<T> {

    @Timed(value = "generic_controller_get_one", description = "Time taken to getOne")
    public T getOne(ID id) {
    }

    @Timed(value = "generic_controller_search", description = "Time taken to search")
    public Page<T> search (int page, int size) {
    }
}
```

An then implemented controllers :

```java
@RestController
public class ModelAController extends GenericController<ModelA> {

}
```

```java
@RestController
public class ModelBController extends GenericController<ModelB> {

}
```

## Question :

Is there a way to time implemented controller with a dynamic metric name like `modela_controller_search` ?

Currently all controllers are timed with `generic_controller_*` metric name.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really put dynamic things into annotations since based on the Java specs, annotation parameters needs to be constant. I don't think there is support for this in Boot, but I think there are two-three ways to make this work.

1. Spring Boot does this for you automatically, check the `http.server.request` metric, it will contain the uri that will separate your controller endpoints.
2. Instead of renaming the metric, you can add a tag that will separate your controllers, take a look at `WebMvcTagsContributor` (also `WebMvcTagsProvider`).
3. If you really want to rename the metric, take a look at Micrometer's [`MeterFilter`](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_transforming_metrics) first. It lets you rename meters and add/remove/modify tags. You can write a `MeterFilter` that renames all of the metrics that's name `startsWith` `generic_controller_*`. You can use the tags that are currently there for the naming but you can also use the `WebMvcTagsContributor` to add new tags as needed.

I'm not recommending separating the controllers in the metric name but I recommend doing it in the tags. Separating controllers in the name will make it harder to aggregate metrics across your controllers, e.g.: show me all of the errors for all of my controllers or show me all of the errors for all of the `GET` calls, etc.

Comment: Thank you for yours answers, I direct my research to these topics, especially MeterFilter.